# AsyncTask Crashing App

Tags: android

Would anyone know why The AsyncTask keeps crashing? Basically in my app, I would like to get the GPS coordinates and have it animate to my position in mapview. Then I would like to use GeoCode to display the current address of my position.

Before I started experimenting with AsyncTask, the app displayed everything perfectly, (Shows current position on map, and tells me which address I am nearest and displays it in a textview) however, it was very slow and laggy because I didnt implement AsyncTask. Now that I have implemented AsyncTask, it gives me errors. Could anyone help?

Heres my code:

```
public class statuspage extends MapActivity {

private MapController mapController;
private MyLocationOverlay myLocation;
Location location;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.statuspage);

    new MapOverlay().execute(); 

    // Get Mapping Controllers etc
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(14);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    // Add the MyLocationOverlay
    myLocation = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocation);
    myLocation.enableMyLocation();
    myLocation.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            mapController.animateTo(myLocation.getMyLocation());

        }
    });
}



class MapOverlay extends AsyncTask<Void,Long,DataPackage> {


    @Override
    protected DataPackage doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        return new DataPackage(); 
    }
}

class DataPackage { 

    public String addressString = null; 
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    public DataPackage(addressString, latitude, longitude) { 
        statuspage.this.addressString = addressString; 
        statuspage.this.latitude = location.getLatitude();
        statuspage.this.longitude = location.getLongitude();

    } 
} 


protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

    // Location Manager Intiation
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String bestProvider;
    String LOCATION_SERVICE = "location";
    locationManager = (LocationManager) statuspage.this
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // More accurate, GPS fix.
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); // More accurate, GPS fix.
    bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if (location != null) {

        // Latitude and Longitude TextView
        TextView etlongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etlongitude);
        TextView etlatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etlatitude);

        // Disables longitude textview Keyboard Popup.
        //InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etlongitude.getWindowToken(), 0);

        // Disables latitude textview Keyboard Popup.
        //InputMethodManager imm2 = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //imm2.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etlatitude.getWindowToken(), 0);



        // Latitude and Longitude TextView Display Coordinates
        etlongitude.setText("Longitude:" + "\n" + (longitude)); 
        /** longitude textview */
        etlatitude.setText("Latitude:" + "\n" + (latitude));
        /** latitude textview */

        addressString = "No address found";

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(statuspage.this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude,
                    longitude, 1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);

                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)


                sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                //sb.append(address.getFeatureName()).append("\n");
                //sb.append(address.getPhone()).append("\n");
                //sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                //sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                //sb.append(address.getCountryName());
            }
            addressString = sb.toString();


            TextView scrollview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
            scrollview.setText("Your location:" + "\n" + "(Accurate to 500 meters)" +"\n" +(addressString));

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        // locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) location);
        locationManager = null;

    } else {

    }

    return false;
}



protected void onResume() {
    myLocation.enableMyLocation();
}

protected void onPause() {
    myLocation.disableMyLocation();
}

public void onBackPressed() {

    // Button OnClick Vibrating Service
    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    // Vibrate Service
    vib.vibrate(50);

    startActivity(new Intent(statuspage.this, AgentPortalActivity.class));
    statuspage.this.finish();

    /** Fading Transition Effect */
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

    return;

}
 }

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;

}
}
```

Here are my logs:

```
 04-12 09:14:15.682: W/dalvikvm(13103): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0x40015578)
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while  executing doInBackground()
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103):   at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103):   at com.jetdelivery.mobile.statuspage$MapOverlay.doInBackground(statuspage.java:119)
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103):   at com.jetdelivery.mobile.statuspage$MapOverlay.doInBackground(statuspage.java:1)
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
 04-12 09:14:15.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13103):   ... 4 more
```

Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is crashing your application because you are attempting to access controls on the UI thread without a handler and in the wrong area of execution.

You should read up on [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html) and how to properly handle interaction with the UI. There is very good information on that page.

> To update your UI, you should implement [`onPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29), which delivers the result from [`doInBackground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) and runs in the UI thread, so you can safely update your UI.

The relevant breaking code in your that needs to be moved to [`onPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29):

```
            // Latitude and Longitude TextView Display Coordinates
            etlongitude.setText("Longitude:" + "\n" + (longitude));
            /** longitude textview */
            etlatitude.setText("Latitude:" + "\n" + (latitude));
            /** latitude textview */


            TextView scrollview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
            scrollview.setText("Your location:" + "\n"
                    + "(Accurate to 500 meters)" + "\n" + (addressString));
```

---

**Edit**: Added example from comment discussion.

```
class DataPackage {
    public String Address = null;
    public double Latitude = 0.0;
    public double Longitude = 0.0;

    public DataPackage(address, lat, lon) {
        this.Address = address;
        this.Latitude = lat;
        this.Longitude = lon;
    }
}
```

...

```
class MapOverlay extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,DataPackage> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {  
        // ... Conditions and logic TRUNCATED for Clarity!
        // This would exist inside of your try block
        return new DataPackage(addressString, latitude, longitude);
        // ... Rest of code
    }

    //...

    protected void onPostExecute(DataPackage result) {
        //Logic that updates the UI based on information in DataPackage object.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that very useful process and threads link. I should have known  that, Noobie mistake. Anyways I did what you suggested, but now, the longitude and latitude in "etlatitude.setText and etlongitude.setText" is giving me errors because "double latitude = location.getLatitude(); and double longitude = location.getLongitude();" are in doInBackground. Should I create a string?

Comment: @JohnNguyen I know the feeling believe me! Yes you will have to separate the data gathering and display logic, luckily `AsyncTask` handles all the hard work for you. In the definition of your task you could modify it to expect the data you need and then return from `doInBackground()` which results will be mapped to `onPostExecute()` for you. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply back. I've been experimenting with what you suggested. I am a little confused about the "class DataPackage" but no worries,  I will keep trying until I get it. You've done an excellent job steering me in the right direction and for that I thank you Quintin. I'll eventually get it!

Comment: @JohnNguyen Well I just made that class to store the data that you appeared to need. It has to be in it's own file and probably exposed as `public`. I am glad to hear that this is helping you and am happy to help you get the information you need!

Comment: I really hate to bother you again Quintin but If you look at my code again, I just re-edit it following your suggestions. Currently, I have two errors and theyre both at DataPackage class. If you can, Would you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
 TextView scrollview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
 scrollview.setText("Your location:" + "\n"
                        + "(Accurate to 500 meters)" + "\n" + (addressString));
```

write the above code in onPostExecute() not in doInBackground().
in doInbackground() we do only network related task and all the UI related task must be in onPostExecute().